# HTML: Siblings of char &#9660;

Tags: html

Char &#9660; in html displays a large down arrow that is very useful in dynamic menus (▼). But it's kinda large. Is there a char for smaller version of this arrow?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're looking for ▾    `&#9662;` BLACK DOWN-POINTING SMALL TRIANGLE.

[Here](http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/geometric_shapes.html) is a complete list.

Answer (score 5):

&#9662; ? (▾)

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25be/index.htm

Comment: I'm going to mark SLaks' response as the answer because he was the first. But I'll give your response one up as my "thank you" :)

Comment: Nothing against SLaks, his answer is perfectly fine, but shouldn't you rather go for the "best" answer? All the three answers as far are subtly different (e.g. different resources are cited and/or multiple solutions are proposed).

Comment: Actually, they both gave the same char code. That is what I was looking for. Nothing against Matthew at all (THANK YOU!!), I'm just trying to be fare :)

Answer (score 2):

You can browse characters at http://www.utf8-chartable.de/.

If you like your current character, you can also wrap it in an inline element (such as `<span>`), and adjust the `font-size` property.